# Single Computer not Accepting Domain Credentials after being added to Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain, dhcp, windows-10

I have one computer that refuses any domain credentials.

This computer is running Win10 and my DCs are Server 2012 r2. After adding this particular computer to the domain it will not accept any domain user password. It simply says "The user name or password is incorrect. Try again".

I know the password works, as the same domain administrator password was used to add the computer to the domain successfully. I've tried multiple domain accounts unsuccessfully and was able to manually add a domain user account under manage users via the local admin. I was not able to add the domain\Administrator because it says there is already an account. I even tried going through the Network ID wizard which accepted the domain admin account and password however it still won't log in.

DNS is pointing correctly to our 2 domain controllers.

It is showing under Domain Computers in AD and the DNS server shows forward and reverse lookups for it. However it is not showing up under DHCP leases even thought it's getting an IP.

It is the only computer with this problem. I have added other computers to the domain recently, before and after. I even wiped and re-installed Windows 10 but the login issue remains.

No real errors under event log but noticed some Time service issues because it was set to manual. Setting to auto start didn't help anything.

Any thoughts? Any help is appreciated! I'm at a loss....

Comment: Do you have a really long computer name? https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/909264

Comment: Thanks for the response but no only 11 characters.

Comment: Was your time out? If the time on the client gets out by a certain amount from your DC, it won't allow logins. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/232386

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue - all domain accounts giving "incorrect password" error, local user account working fine - and a reboot fixed it for me.

I realize this question is several years old, but at least here's a fix that has actually worked for the problem described in this question, at least once!

Answer (score -2):

i have the same issue with Microsoft Windows 8.1.
First of all make sure you have provide an accurate name for system means doesn't conflict with other computer in the network & than try.
if you have same still now -->
Go to TCP/IP Properties & add DNS Server address as well as global DNS Server adress manually & try once again to  configure the system as a member of domain.
if you can't able to login after that than you have need to reserve IP address for this system in the function of DHCP server.
You can also use any other Domain User's name & password as an alternate of Administrator & Password.

Let me know if you have same issue after that.

Comment: Appreciate the response but I addressed most of your suggestions in my initial post:  it will not accept any domain user password, DNS is pointing correctly to our 2 domain controllers, Computer name is simple and not previously used for example: Accounting3, Accounting4

Comment: note: I am able to map network drives using domain user credentials under the local account. Still i cannot log into the computer with those same domain credentials.

Comment: Can you please provide a screen short that what error message you got when the system do not accepting the domain credentials

Comment: It's not a special error. Its the same one you get on any computer when the password is incorrect. "The user name or password is incorrect. Try again"

Comment: ok may i take the remote session of this computer

Answer (score -2):

You open server active directory service.there are all domain pc user show in ad then you reset password perticulor user which you use on that pc. password change next logon option check mark.

Comment: This question is over 2 years old....

Comment: Can you explain why that would help?